# What does "team collision" in CS:GO mean?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

While joining different types of matches in Counter Strike: Global Offensive, I noticed in some of them Team collision is turned on and in some off. I didn't noticed any differences.

What does "Team collision" means in CS:GO?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Team Collision determines whether you can walk through your team-mates or not.

If team collision is on, then your team-mates will act the same way as an enemy when you come into contact with them, namely, they will be able to block doors and the like with their body.

If team collision is off, then you will be able to freely walk through your team-mates.

This is a mostly anti griefing option, so that people can't purposely block doors to prevent their team-mates from getting out of spawn. It is also a tactical concern, as you can't stuff a bunch of players in one position if team collision is on.

Keep in mind that enemies will always have collision on.

Comment: Less anti griefing and more of a competitive/casual related feature AFAIK.

Comment: @Kotsu Yes that's true, but the main difference in terms of collision between a competitive and casual game is the chances of griefing occuring. Although I suppose in a casual game someone could unintentionally block a door, which I suppose isn't griefing.